# DirectX 9 Device. Creating vertex and index buffers while rendering.(2 threads)

Tags: c++, multithreading, directx

I've been looking for a answer to this question for some time. Anyone know how to do it?

I've got some ideas, can you tell me if they are valid and which is the best one to use(if there are actually suitable solutions).

1. Create a single directx9 device. Make a copy for the different threads. Render the loading screen(with already loaded buffers) while loading the new level assets and creating their Vertex and index buffers.
2. Create 2 different directx9 devices. One for each thread. One device is responsible for rendering only(and is attached to the window) and the other has no rendering surface and is taking care of making and filling the buffers.
3. Create a device with a thread safety flag(I think there is such thing, but it may not be called this way) and do the same as in 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well, I need to load my level while rendering a loading screen. Loading level -> IO(loading from hard disk), then creating directx objects(buffers, textures, shaders...) and filling them.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to load a level, then you don't really need separate thread for that. You could repaint scene while loading resources, for example. I'd advise to avoid multithreading unless you can't live without it.

If you still want multithreading, pass [`D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into [IDirect3D9::CreateDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that DirectX SDK explicitly warns that using this flag may degrade performance.

Creating single device is preferred solution, i.e. I"d advise to use #1 .

It Is possible to [share resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) between several devices, but this functionality is available only on windows vista. Because people still use WinXP today, if you use something like that, your users will hate you.